# default fontawesome favicon but different color? possibly through class or css

Tags: html, css, frontend, favicon

I am uncertain if these are native to bootstrap only, but I'm using the default favicons on my HTML.

```
<i class="fa fa-video-camera"></i>
```

[favicons cheatsheet](https://fontawesome.bootstrapcheatsheets.com/)

I want to know if there is a simple way of changing the color of this favicon, such as inserting another class like alert or by putting a #fff for example on the .css

I am trying to avoid a response such as making my own colored version and using it on a

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/PATH_TO_STATIC_FAVICON/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon"> <link rel="icon" href="/PATH_TO_ANIMATED_FAVICON/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
```

Cheers

Comment: You cannot use those icons as a favicon.

Comment: @str isn't this using an icon as a favicon?  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/PATH_TO_STATIC_FAVICON/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
<link rel="icon" href="/PATH_TO_ANIMATED_FAVICON/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">


extracted from

 https://www.favicon.cc/?action=icon&file_id=875181

Comment: _“isn't this using an icon as a favicon?”_ - that one is, but the code you have shown in your question (`<i class="fa fa-video-camera">`) has little to do with that. And no, you can not change anything about an actual favicon via CSS, that will only ever use the image/icon as-is.

Comment: @misorude that was pseudocode

Comment: @Mr-Programs A favicon is not the same as an icon. Your question does not make sense, especially in combination with your own answer.

Comment: fontawesome* favicon then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

---USING HTML

```
<i class="text-success fa fa-video-camera"></i>
```

·  "text-success"

[Bootstrap color classes](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/utilities/colors/)

---USING CSS

```
.fa-video-camera{color:green;}
```

· "color:green"

--- for specific hex

·"color:#fff"

for specific hex I supose you would need the css code used above but with the #hex as you would normally do

--info**

"class fa" seems bootstrap-only, since I tried it on a stripped down html and didn't work

Answer (score 2):

Hope this will help you,

With the help of [Bootstrap Color Utility](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/utilities/colors/) you can achieve this.

For example to achieve `green` color you can use the class `text-success`

`<i class="text-success fa fa-video-camera"></i>`

Comment: great, it also works, 


a bit weird that they linked class fa with text classes instead of other elements, i have a list of all the text-<color> at my reference guide

Comment: btw, do you know if these class="fa" are native to bootstrap only or to navigators in general?

Comment: Bootstrap uses [Font Awesome](https://fontawesome.com/) icon sets. So Font Awesome prefix the icons with `fa`

Comment: If I have answered your question kindly accept the answer!!

Comment: hi there, edit to include all possibilities like on my own reply and ill gladly accept your answer

Answer (score 0):

You can't use font awesome icons as a favicons. Those are just for styling your html.